# HttpWebRequest throws 404 error in .NET Core 2.2 but works in 3.0

Tags: http, asp.net-core, httpwebrequest

I found out that making a HTTP GET request works in a simple .NET Core console application like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string url = "https://www.zdnet.com/article/quantum-entanglement-breakthrough-could-boost-encryption-secure-communications/#ftag=RSSbaffb68";
        var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0";
        var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        var respStream = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), true);
        var html = respStream.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Now I change the framework in the csproj file from

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
```

to

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
```

and run the same code again. This time, it throws a 404 error:

> System.Net.WebException: "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

Why does the exactly same code throw 404 errors in .NET Core 2.2? It's an relatively simple request and the `HttpWebRequest` API is not very new. I also got 404 errors when using the newer `HttpClient`. Does anyone know what have changed in .NET Core 3.0 that could explain this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I analyzed the requests using [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/). It allows decrypting tls traffic, which is not easily possible using traditional network tools like Wireshark. It's very easy: Just download the mitmproxy binaries, execute the `mitmweb` binary and add the proxy to the `HttpWebRequest` instance:

```
req.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://localhost:8080");
req.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

For simplicity, I didn't add the MITM certificate to the truststore, since it's just for local testing. After capturing a working request with .NET 3.0 and a failing 2.2, I saw that 2.2 redirects from `https://www.zdnet.com/article/quantum-entanglement-breakthrough-could-boost-encryption-secure-communications/#ftag=RSSbaffb68` to `https://www.zdnet.com/article/quantum-entanglement-breakthrough-could-boost-encryption-secure-communications/#ftag=rssbaffb68` where the second request returns 404.

3.0 seems to remove those hashtag, because it requests `https://www.zdnet.com/article/quantum-entanglement-breakthrough-could-boost-encryption-secure-communications/` which works. So I fixed this in my .NET 2.2 application with a simple workaround:

```
var uri = new Uri(url);
url = $"{uri.Scheme}://{uri.Host}{uri.PathAndQuery}";
var document = GetDocumentNode(url);
```

This removes the hashtag parameter from the URL, resulting in no more 404 errors.

Comment: Possibly this bug ([#30306](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30306)) in .NET Core 2.2, which is fixed in .NET Core 3.x. Because of this bug, the [fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier#Basics) won't be deleted, which should actually happen.